# Elasticsearch Not Logging After Upgrade to 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch

After upgrading elasticsearch to v1.4 it has stopped logging. It was working fine with 1.3 but stopped after upgrading.

My settings look like the following:

```
"cluster_name": "clustername",
...
"settings": {
    "path": {
       "data": "/var/lib/elasticsearch",
       "work": "/tmp/elasticsearch",
       "home": "/usr/share/elasticsearch",
       "conf": "/etc/elasticsearch",
       "logs": "/var/log/elasticsearch"
},
```

In /var/log/elasticsearch the correct file exists: clustername.log but it hasn't been updated since the upgrade. Meanwhile the server works fine to add and query data. I get the feeling that perhaps the new version has disabled logging, but I don't know how to adjust this. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ES now reads any file in /etc/elasticsearch/ called logging.*

So check it there are any logging.*.dpkg-new or similar there from packaging and move them elsewhere.

Otherwise, try sudo su-ing to elasticsearch and starting it manually (look in the init.d script) and see if it reports any errors to stderr on startup.

Bug reports:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8292

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/7457